# Rendering json data fields from mysql db in rails response object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, rails-api

I have a rails 4.2 app that uses mysql db 5.7 which supports json fields. So my user model has a field called display_pic which is a json object.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :display_pic, JSON
    ....
```

In the action get_user I render user as follows

```
def get_user
  @u = User.where(...)
  render json: { user: @u }
end
```

The problem is that the json field `display_pic` doesn't come out as a nested json object, rather it is rendered as a string. I would like to have a response like the following

```
{ 
  "user": {
     "name": "some name", 
     "email": "some email",
     "display_pic": {
         "url": "http://someurl.com",
         "width": "400px",
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a better way to do this, but you can format it as json in the serializer.

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :name
  attribute :email
  attribute :display_pic

  def display_pic
    JSON.parse(object.display_pic)
  end
end
```

Comment: Probably the best solution, however, a quicker solution turned out to be just overriding as_json. thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: Maybe you should use both solution overriding as_json with super(options.merge(methods: [:display_pic])

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code it will solve your problem:

```
def get_user
  @u = User.where(...)
  render json: { user: JSON.parse(@u)}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the method .as_json ?

```
def get_user
  @u = User.where(...)
  render json: @u.as_json
end
```

You should have not need to set serialize :display_pic, :JSON, but you can overload the method in your user.rb class in order to get on response references or methods results authomatically loaded on your front end:

```
class PlayerCharacter < ApplicationRecord

      [...]
      def as_json(options = {})
        super(options.merge(include: [ :reference1, :reference2]).merge(methods: [:method_name1, :method_name2])
      end
end
```

EDIT:
you could add display_pic as follow:

```
class PlayerCharacter < ApplicationRecord

      [...]
      def as_json(options = {})
        super(options.merge(include: [ :display_pic])
      end
end
```

Comment: include: [:display_pic] does not do the job. however, I liked the idea of dealing with it in as_json. 
`def as_json(options = {})
  h = super(options)
  h[:display_pic] = JSON.parse(display_pic)
  h
 end`

This did the job. Thanks for the answer :)